# Is there a C# secure socket other than SSLStream?

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl

.NET 2.0 provides only the System.Net.Security.SslStream class for secure sockets in .NET 2.0 and higher, but this uses the Stream interface, which provides the blocking Read/Write members and asynchronous Begin{Read,Write} members.

I'm looking for a class that provides functionality similar to System.Net.Sockets.Socket. Specifically, something resembling Poll/Select, so I can handle multiple sockets in a single thread without blocking.

The [mentalis security library](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/seclib/docs/ssl_upgrade.html) supplies a SecureSocket class, but is explicitly unsupported for versions greater than .NET 1.1.

Comment: Due to bugs in both the Microsoft and Mono implementation of SslStream, I am also looking for a 3rd party implementation. It seems, mentalis is old and unsupported (last update 2007). Eldos SecureBlackbox looks like it would be fine, but if I want to distribute applications that use it, it will cost me around $1,800 USD. I am looking for another .NET SSL/TLS library. Haven't found an answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682744/c-secure-sockets-ssl) to a related question suggests using a secure 3rd-party library on top of Socket:

> If you don't like how SSLStream is implemented (it's really limited in
>   functionality), you can take SSL/TLS components of [SecureBlackbox
>   (our product)](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssl.php) and use them on
>   top of Socket class of .NET framework. This way you'll be able to get
>   SSL in asynchronous mode etc for both client-side and server-side
>   sockets.

Comment: The features I require of the SecureBlackbox would cost me over 1000 EUR. Mentalis's library is open source, but does not support .NET 2.0 or higher.
Do you know of any other libraries that provide this functionality?

Comment: If you only need SSL, the cost of the license starts from less than $200, which is far less, than 1000 EUR. Please contact EldoS for assistance in choosing the right license scheme.

Comment: The link is broken. You should have copied the content :)

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray: that answer was downvoted 4 times, but it basically contained this: _"If you don't like how SSLStream is implemented (it's really limited in functionality), you can take SSL/TLS components of [SecureBlackbox (our product)](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssl.php) and use them on top of Socket class of .NET framework. This way you'll be able to get SSL in asynchronous mode etc for both client-side and server-side sockets."_